Are 2D and higher-D conformal field theories gapless?
I am reading a CFT lecture note by D. Simmons-Duffin. In his lecture note, the mass gap $m_{gap}$ of a QFT is given by the difference in energy of its ground state and the first excited state (p5, Phys 229ab Advanced Mathematical Methods:
Conformal Field Theory, D. Simmons-Duffin),
$$
m_{gap}:=E_1-E_0.
$$
Given a gapped ($m_{gap}\neq0$) Poincare-invariant theory, suppose that the one-point function of  operator $\phi$ vanishes. Then the Euclidean two-point function of $\phi$ reads
$$
\begin{align}
\langle 0|\phi(x^0,x^i=0)\phi(0,0)|0\rangle=&\langle0|e^{Hx^0} \phi(0,0)e^{-Hx^0}\phi(0,0)|0\rangle\\
=&\sum_{a=0}\langle0|e^{E_0x^0} \phi(0,0)e^{-E_ax^0}|E_a\rangle\langle E_a|\phi(0,0)|0\rangle\\
=&\sum_{a=1}e^{-(E_a-E_0)x^0}|\langle0|\phi(0,0)|E_a\rangle|^2\tag{1}.
\end{align}
$$
Eq. (1) tells us that $m_{gap}$ defines a correlation lengths $\xi:=1/m_{gap}$. The correlation functions of local operators contain an exponential decay of $e^{-|x|/\xi}$, when $|x|\gg \xi$.
Back to CFT on $\mathbb{R}^d$, the global conformal symmetry fixes the two-point function of $\phi$ to be
$$
\langle\phi(x)\phi(0)\rangle=|x|^{-2\Delta},\tag{2}
$$
which, as opposed to (1), decays polynomially. We cannot read the correlation length from (2) and this makes sense because CFT doesn't have a special scale. Our theory should be scale-invariant. So from this point of view, we can say that all CFTs are gapless, that is we have $m^{CFT}_{gap}=0$.
However, we also know that the spectrum of the Hamiltonian of a CFT is given by the scaling dimension of all operators it contains. For a unitary CFT with finite primary operators, such as 2D rational CFTs, obviously, we have a non-vanishing $m_{gap}$, which equals the minimal non-zero scaling dimension of the theory. For instance, for the critical 2D Ising model, by definition we should have $m_{gap}=\Delta_{\sigma}=1/8$, where $\sigma$ is the Ising spin.
My question is, how do I reconcile these two views? Is CFT truly gapless or not?

The spectrum of any QFT depends non-trivially on the background geometry on which it is being studied.
CFT's are best defined on compact surfaces, such as ${\mathbb R}_{time} \times S^{d-1}$. In this case, the CFT is gapped with $m_{gap} = \frac{\Delta_1}{R}$ where $R$ is the radius of the $S^{d-1}$ and $\Delta_1$ is the scaling dimension of the first excited state.
On ${\mathbb R}^d$, the theory is gapless. The spectrum can be roughly recovered from the above by taking $R \to \infty$ (though this limit is quite subtle).

Thanks, Prahar. I agree with you that CFTs defined on compact surfaces are gapped. Since in this case we can clearly define the CFT Hamiltonian, for example, on a 2D cylinder with radius $R$ we have $H=\frac{1}{R}(L_0+\bar L_0-\frac{c}{12})$. Then as you said $m_{gap}=\Delta_1/R$. But, it seems I still cannot read out the mass gap (or the correlation length) of the theory from the 2pt function on the cylinder. Do you know what's going on?

The 2pt-function of a spinless primary on a 2D cylinder is $\langle O(w_1,\bar{w}_1)O(w_2,\bar{w}2)\rangle{cyl}=\left|\frac{1}{R^2}w_1w_2\right|^{-\Delta}\cdot\big|R\log({w_1}/{w_2})\big|^{-2\Delta}$. I still can't read out the feature scale ($\xi$) in (1) from this expression...
